# Why no " in message?

Tags: php, quote

I have a webradio station and in my request form, the listeners can send in request. Every sign works perfect (I live in Sweden so we have special letters like ÅÄÖ), but for some reason, every special sign except the sign " dont' work when we read them in the admin panel. The "-sign becomes &quot: in the adminpanel for the DJ's when we read the messages. Whats wrong? Is it the code or could it be a security thing for scripts?

I can post the code for the request form here:

```
include("config.php"); 

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$isbanned = mysql_query("SELECT * from rlbans WHERE `ip` = '$ip'");
$banned = mysql_num_rows($isbanned);

if ($banned >= '1') {
    echo("Sorry, but you are blocked from the request form!");
} else { 
    if ($_POST) { 
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO requests (name, msg, ip) VALUES ('".$security->makeSafe($_REQUEST['name'])."', '".$security->makeSafe($_REQUEST['msg'])."', '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."')");  
        echo "Thanks for your message!";
    } else { 
        echo '<form method="post"><table border="0"><tr><td>Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="name"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Message:</td><td><textarea name="msg"></textarea></td></tr><tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Send"></tr></form>';
    }
}
```

I don't know what the code "`('".$security->makeSafe($_REQUEST['name'])."', '".$security->makeSafe($_REQUEST['msg'])`" means.. Maybe it's that? And where whould I looke at it do you think?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Everything is happening inside `makeSafe`, so you're going to have to open up that class definition to see why. Look inside your `config.php` include file for the `$security` object

Comment: We can't see what the `makeSafe` method is doing, but I'd take a guess that it's encoding the string for your sql query which will change anything like `<` or `"` to `&lt;` and `&quot;` respectively.This is common practice for security reasons. Also, before you get blasted about it on here you should really update this code to use `mysqli_` instead of `mysql_`

Comment: Do you have the display code as well as the request code?

Comment: What's your `requests` table and mysql default charset?

Comment: Default charset is latin1_swedish_c1